# mysql database how to select column with repeated entires after inner join

Tags: mysql

I have a database with 3 tables

> article with the fields: id: int name: varchar(255) text: text
>
> tag with the fields: id: int name: varchar(255))
>
> article_tag with the fields: id: int article_id: int (foreign key =>
>   article.id) tag_id: int (foreign key => tag.id)

I want to be able to look for articles associated with multiple tags.

If I do:

```
SELECT article.name FROM article 
JOIN article_tag ON article.id = article_tag.article_id
JOIN tag  ON tag.id = article_tag.tag_id
WHERE tag.name  IN ('science', 'technology', ... );
```

I get back every article*(the number of tags it has); which was expected.

My question: is there a way to refine it so that it lists in descending order of frequency of article.id (with the effect being the more requested tags that it matches the higher it is in list) and or so that it only returns records that match all tags (number of occurrences in result = number of tags).

Thanks, and sorry this question wasn't better formatted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, this should do the trick:

```
SELECT
  article.id,
  article.name,
  COUNT(*) AS TagCount
FROM article
JOIN article_tag ON article.id = article_tag.article_id
JOIN tag  ON tag.id = article_tag.tag_id
WHERE tag.name  IN ('science', 'technology', ... )
GROUP BY
  article.id,
  article.name
ORDER BY
  TagCount DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the count of repeated articles and order them

```
SELECT article.name ,COUNT( article.name) AS acount FROM article 
JOIN article_tag ON article.id = article_tag.article_id
JOIN tag  ON tag.id = article_tag.tag_id
WHERE tag.name  IN ('science', 'technology', ... )
GROUP BY article.name
ORDER BY acount DESC
```